# ReactJs - Function in Render doesn't Show Up

Tags: reactjs

**

> **Update: This questions has an answer that worked. It is important to**
>   **note that even though you have a return statement in your function**
>   **called within render(), it is still important to wrap the entire loop**
>   **in a parent "return" in order for it to render properly on state**
>   **change. This is a different common issue where state is not updated**
>   **properly.**

I have the following ClientList component, which shows a list of customers retrieved from database.

Below in the Render() function, i am calling the showList function which will display a list once this.props.clientList Reducer is populated.

Problem is... if I were to call the showList codes directly inside the Render() method, it will show.

IF i were to put it in a showList function, and call {this.showList} it doesn't shows up in the render.

I have the screen shot of the console as well, showing that the list is populated already.

Is this method disallowed? I see many tutorials teaching us to do this but it's not working for me. What are the restrictions to use this method to return the codes for render?

```
class ClientList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            clientId : ''

        }
        this.getClientList = this.getClientList.bind(this);
        this.showList = this.showList.bind(this);
        console.log('initializing', this.props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getClientList();
    }

    getClientList() {
        if (this.props.actions) {
        this.props.actions.getClientList(); //This is an ajax action to retrieve from Api
        }

    }

    showList() {

            //If i put all the codes below directly in Render, it will show.
            console.log('props from showList', this.props.clientList);

                        this.props.clientList && Object.keys(this.props.clientList).reverse().map((index,key) => {

                     return (

                     <div key={key}>
                     <div><a onClick={() => this.showProfileBox(this.props.clientList[index].customerId)}>Name: {this.props.clientList[index].firstname} {this.props.clientList[index].lastname}</a><span className="pull-right"><Link to={"/client/" + this.props.clientList[index].customerId}>Edit</Link></span></div>

                     </div>
                    );
                })
        }

    render() {
        console.log('rendering', this.props);
        return (

                <div>

                <Col xs={12} md={8}>
                <h1>Client List</h1>

                { this.showList() }  // <= This function doesn't print
                </Col>

                </div>
            )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        clientList: state.clientList,

    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {  
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(clientActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClientList);
```

[image: clientList reducer populated but doesn't render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should return the value from showList() method.  As of now you were returning the value for map method, but not for the entire showList() method.  Thats y it is painting nothing in the page
`

```
showList() {
    return (
 //removed unnecessary {}
       this.props.clientList && Object.keys(this.props.clientList).reverse().map((index,key) => {    
          return (
             <div key={key}>
               <div><a onClick={() => this.showProfileBox(this.props.clientList[index].customerId)}>Name: {this.props.clientList[index].firstname} {this.props.clientList[index].lastname}</a><span className="pull-right"><Link to={"/client/" + this.props.clientList[index].customerId}>Edit</Link></span></div>
             </div>
             );
      })
  );
}
```

`

Comment: there's an extra { after your first return which doesn't work, But if i remove that curly bracket it works!

Comment: sorry!!.  I haven't checked in fiddle..I just pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `bind` `showList` in the constructor.

Remove it and you should be fine.

Also, as @JayabalajiJ pointed out, you need to return something out of `showList` otherwise you won't see the final result.

```js
class ClientList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
     console.log('click')
  }
  
  showList() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>From showList</button>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click-me</button>
        {this.showList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ClientList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial how does `this.props.clientList` look like? Maybe it's empty.

Comment: Apparently the answer above about returning the whole loop works! THank u!

Comment: Also please close the question by accepting any of the answer